# OS X Mavericks wakes my Mac from sleep every hour or so

Tags: sleep-wake, macos, mac-mini, console

Ever since upgrading to Mavericks, it looks like my Mac Mini wakes from sleep about once an hour or so. In the Console, I get the following message:

```
Oct 30 02:12:06 gary-mac WindowServer[93]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [89885620192550]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
Oct 30 02:12:06 gary-mac WindowServer[93]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
```

Anyone know why it's doing this?

Usually when the computer wakes from sleep, whether manually or automatically, there is a "Wake Reason" line, but in this case there isn't one. My guess is that this is because since Mavericks, "Sleep" doesn't actually put the Mini to sleep. It seems to be more "on" than it used to be. Is there a way to revert the behavior to how it was before Mavericks?

Comment: Seems to be waking up every two hours or so here.

Comment: Have you got the `Wake for Ethernet network access` option checked in `System preferences > Energy saver` ?

Comment: @Laurent I tried that not long after commenting here this morning.  I just checked and that seems to have fixed it. Unlike Gary, however, I did have a Wake Reason line every time.

Comment: I definitely have "Wake for network access" DISABLED. I have everything on Energy Saver disabled actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had "File sharing" enabled in my "Sharing" System Preferences pane. I've always had this setting enabled, and I could sleep my Mac just fine before Mavericks. However starting with Mavericks, if I sleep my Mac with "File sharing" enabled, then the Mac won't sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Since I started to share files on my Mac, I had the insomnia issue as well. There is a great little tool called *PleaseSleep* which is freeware and supports Mavericks. It will help your Mac to stay asleep.

[Direct download link](http://files.downloadnow.com/s/software/13/42/55/28/PleaseSleep.dmg?token=1460238081_96f4d50b427cdfeeb4bcb999e95604a3&fileName=PleaseSleep.dmg)

Unfortunately, the product is not maintained anymore, as the developer [Dragonone.com](http://www.dragonone.com) stopped.